# PHP or Perl PDF Library that provides DRM with offline expiry/sharing prevention

Tags: pdf, drm

Does anybody know of a PDF library that provides DRM functionality to cover offline expiry and sharing prevention?  Needs to be PHP or Perl based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember doing some research on this a year or so back.  A lot of the DRM features provided in the PDF format are vendor specific extensions.  The main DRM features are locked to the Adobe Acrobat Reader by a key/certificate embedded into the documents themselves.  When I researched it, the only software capable of generating this key/certificate was Adobe's own.  A quick look suggests this hasn't changed.

In summary, I don't think there's any software out there, besides Adobes (LiveCycle for example), which can unlock these features for you.

Comment: Which is exactly why such methods never really gained traction in the market apart from very small niche markets.

Comment: At least sharing protection, print protection ect. you can also cover with tcpdf like I wrote in my post above.

Answer (score -2):

I found an article telling about php libs, that can handle the drm stuff.

e.g. [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) would work like this

```php
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'LETTER');
$pdf->SetProtection(
    ['print', 'modify', 'copy', 'annot-forms', 'fill-forms', 'extract', 'assemble', 'print-high'],
    'test123', 'test456', 3
);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
file_put_contents('output.pdf', $pdf->Output('', 'S'));
```

[mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) could do similar stuff, but with lower encryption.

I recommend reading the Original article [How to encrypt a PDF document in PHP](https://peterdev.pl/php-how-to-encrypt-a-pdf-document/), that tells als pros/cons of the different libs that could handle DRM.